# What sorts of models are out there for cooperative games with strategic elements?

Tags: reference-request, game-theory

I want to look at games where there are coalitions as well as individuals who are trying to maximize personal utility. What papers are out there for these sorts of games?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you add `reference-request` to your tags.